# Calling JS function from MongoDB aggregation pipeline

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

For my use-case, I'm using Mongo aggregation function with JS support as mentioned in the [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/).

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        $set:
            {
                result: {
                    $function:
                        {
                            body: someFunction,
                            args: [
                                "$someArgument"
                            ],
                            lang: "js"
                        }
                }
            }
    }
]

var someFunction = function(argument){
// some opeartion on argument
return result;
}
```

And this pipeline is working correctly. Now I'm trying to separate some generic code from someFunction, to other genericFunction which can be used by other methods also. So I tried couple of ways to do that, and I'm facing issue in those,

**Apprach#1:**
Calling 2nd JS function, from 1st JS function,

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        $set:
            {
                result: {
                    $function:
                        {
                            body: specificFunction,
                            args: [
                                "$someArgument"
                            ],
                            lang: "js"
                        }
                }
            }
    }
]

var specificFunction = function(argument){
genericFuction(argument);
// some opeartion on argument
return result;
}

var genericFunction = function(argument){
// some opeartion on argument
return result;
}
```

While creating pipeline there is no issue, but while running the pipeline, it is throwing an error as
`"errmsg" : "PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: ReferenceError: genericFunction is not defined :`

**Approach #2:**
Defining genericFuction in db.system.js, loading all scripts, and running the pipeline.

```
db.system.js.save({"_id" : "genericFuction", "value" : function(arg) { // some Code; return result}})

db.loadServerScripts();

// Same pipeline and specificFunction as above
```

But it gave me the same error,
`"errmsg" : "PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: ReferenceError: genericFunction is not defined :`

**Approach #3:**
Both speceficFunction and genericFunction in db.system.js

```
db.system.js.save({"_id" : "genericFuction", "value" : function(arg) { // some Code; return result}})

db.system.js.save({"_id" : "specificFuction", "value" : function(arg) { genericFuction(arg); // some Code; 
return result}})

db.loadServerScripts();

var pipeline = [
    { $set: {
            result : {
                $let: {
                    vars: { arg1 : "$someArgument"
                    },
                    in: specificFunction("$$arg1")
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

With this I'm able to access genericFunction from specificFunction but not the argument passed to any of the method. If both methods are simple and not using passed variables it is working fine, but if I'm trying to use argument within methods then it is failing with error on some field of argument.
`"errmsg" : "PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: TypeError: arg.someField is undefined`

Please let me know, what is the correct way of calling one JS function from another JS in the MongoDB aggregation framework.